# Upload most recent file to FTP server using PowerShell ISE or WinSCP

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I want to upload the recent XML file from my local folder into FTP server using PowerShell automation script. I searched through internet and found that it can be achieved through WinSCP in PowerShell. Anyone have any information how to achieve this using PowerShell ISE or WinSCP?

[image]

I want to upload `ABCDEF.XML` which has 10pm timestamp from my local folder to FTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's WinSCP example for your exact task: [Upload the most recent file in PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_most_recent_file).

The only modification you need to do is that the script is for SFTP, while you want FTP. Though the change is trivial and pretty obvious:

```
try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"
 
    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
        HostName = "example.com"
        UserName = "user"
        Password = "mypassword"
    }
 
    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
 
    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)
 
        $localPath = "c:\toupload"
        $remotePath = "/home/user"
 
        # Select the most recent file.
        # The !$_.PsIsContainer test excludes subdirectories.
        # With PowerShell 3.0, you can replace this with
        # Get-ChildItem -File switch 
        $latest =
            Get-ChildItem -Path $localPath |
            Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} |
            Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
            Select-Object -First 1
 
        # Any file at all?
        if ($latest -eq $Null)
        {
            Write-Host "No file found"
            exit 1
        }
 
        # Upload the selected file
        $session.PutFiles(
            [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($latest.FullName),
            [WinSCP.RemotePath]::Combine($remotePath, "*")).Check()
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }
 
    exit 0
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
}
```

---

*If you find anything confusing about the code, you have to be more specific.*

---

Though easier is to use [plain WinSCP script with its `-latest` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file#scripting) from a plain Windows batch file (or PowerShell if you prefer).